# notifydatasetchanged() on custom base adapter having JSONArray

Tags: android, notifydatasetchanged

I made a custom base adapter class in which I pass the context of activity and a JSONArray. I use this JSONArray data to set all the views. But the notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter is not working. Do I have to pass a string array or arraylist of strings in the adapter for notifyDataSetChanged() to work? Will it not work if I pass JSONArray?

My Custom Adapter class code:

```
public class InboxMessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity act;
SharedPreferences prefs;
LayoutInflater Inflater;
JSONArray arrayOfMessages;

public InboxMessagesAdapter(Activity a, JSONArray arry) {
    act = a;
    arrayOfMessages = arry;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(a);
    Inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayOfMessages.length();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View v1 = arg1;
    try {
        final int x = arg0;
        JSONObject js = arrayOfMessages.getJSONObject(arg0);
        v1 = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_inbox, null);
        TextView titleOfMessage = (TextView) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.msg_inbox_title);
        TextView timeOfMessage = (TextView) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.msg_inbox_time);
        final CheckBox selectMessage = (CheckBox) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.msg_inbox_check_button);
        ImageView attachment = (ImageView) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.msg_inbox_attachment);
        ImageView starStatus = (ImageView) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.msg_inbox_addtofav);
        if (js.getString("StarStatus").equals("0"))
            starStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_add_to_fav_normal);
        else
            starStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_add_to_fav_pressed);
        if (js.getString("AttachmentStatus").equals("0"))
            attachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        titleOfMessage.setText(js.getString("MessageSubject"));
        String arr[] = js.getString("MessageDate").split(" ");
        try {
            timeOfMessage.setText(arr[1] + arr[2]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            timeOfMessage.setText(js.getString("MessageDate"));
        }
        v1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    Intent in = new Intent(act, MessageActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("data", arrayOfMessages.getJSONObject(x)
                            .toString());
                    act.startActivity(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v1;
}
}
```

Comment: Why you passed `JsonArray`? store data in `ArrayList` and passed `ArrayList`

Comment: Best way is to pass arraylist as a parameter in which your all Json Data in adapter Constructor.

Comment: @SimplePlan Do you mean to say JSONArray will not work here?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Do you mean to say JSONArray will not work here?

Comment: @berserk i am not said it's not work but the best way is put your all data into `ArrayList` and passed to `Adapter`

Comment: @berserk Why not. It should be work

Comment: @SimplePlan Can you explain why it is not working?

Comment: @PiyushGupta  Can you explain why it is not working?

Comment: That is very poor performance to have all that cpu cycles inside Adapter's `getView` method

Comment: @Daniel Do you mean to say I must parse each JSONObject into String arrays before sending to adapter?

Comment: @berserk: yes, I do, otherwise, when scrolling the listView you probably will see some lag cause each time an item of the listView is rendered it must call getView.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, now I understood, thanks :) But still the main problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

you must be updating a different object of `arrayOfMessages` create a function in adapter like:

```
public void setArrayOfMessages(JSONArray arrayOfMessages){
this.arrayOfMessages=arrayOfMessages;
}
```

and before calling `notifyDataSetChanged` all this:

```
adapter.setArrayOfMessages(object);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for the post:) If this is he case, how do the arraylist got updated itself? I did the same thing, but replaced JSONArray with an arraylist, and it works.

Comment: in case of array list if you change the reference it wont work. What you do is clear the list and add new element and so keeping the same reference of the list that was added to the adapter.

Comment: Well I did it the same way as I was doing with JSONArray. Everything is same. The arraylist used to set views is a global arraylist which is initialized in the counstructor. I mean to say that everything is same in both cases, just the data types are different(JSONArray and Arraylist<String>). So, how is it working with arraylist and not with JSONArray?

Answer (score 0):

Better take your data from Json Array into an Arraylist or List and then apply notifyDataSetChanged.